# How many *Non-Native* speakers of Egyptian Arabic are there world wide?

Tags: arabic, second-lang-acquisition, egyptian

Every time I try to look this up, it always gives me the number for native speakers. I'm not looking for that. I specifically want to know how prevalent Egyptian Arabic is as a ***second language*** around the world. Only 68% of Egyptian citizens speak Egyptian Arabic natively but the other 32% have to have some kind of fluency in it, right? Not to mention, Egyptian Arabic is often the language used in Arabic movies, tv shows, and books. So there's a lot of people in the Arab world who have learned Egyptian Arabic as a second language.

Every article I find will say that Egyptian Arabic is spoken in Iraq, Israel, Jordan, Kuwait, Libya, Saudi Arabia, United Arab Emirates, and Yemen, but they never specify how many people in those countries speak it. I've also tried looking at the demographics for some of those countries and they almost never mention Egyptian Arabic. The closest I got was a demographic chart that said roughly 600,000 of Saudi Arabians speak Egyptian Arabic but that was only counting Egyptian immigrants to the country and not the people in Saudi Arabia who learned it as a second language. I'm not sure where else to look, so I came here hoping someone would either know the answer or know a good place to look.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about sociology or demography, not about linguistics

Comment: @bytebuster Then where should I ask my question? There's no Arabic Stack Exchange. I looked.

Comment: Yeah, this is on topic. There are empirical and linguistic ways to investigate it, though it may have not been done yet.

Comment: There is also [opendata.se] where you can ask for open datasets containing such kind of information. But I don't see why a question on language statistics could be off-topic here.

Comment: I'm also not sure why there's a vote to close as "opinion-based". Surely the number of L1 and L2 speakers of a language is not an opinion, even if it's potentially difficult to measure and depends on how you define "non-native" etc.

Comment: The criteria for being an "L2 speaker" are a matter of person opinion, unless you define it somehow. The OP seems to equate exposure to the language with being an L2 speaker, given the invocation of movies etc. How many Norwegians are for that reason L2 speakers of Swedish?